# Is there a way to globally detect paste, cut, copy events using UIPasteboard in swift?

Tags: swift, global, pasteboard

Hello I would like to know any time a user cut, copy, paste using `UIPasteboard` is this possible to detect at a global level? When the user copies, cuts or paste the app is active, those events are the events I would like to track.

Comment: Globally across the entire OS or just globally in your app? I'm pretty sure the former is not possible. Your app isn't even necessarily running, let alone active, when a random copy-paste happens. iOS isn't obligated to tell you what happens in other apps.

Comment: updated title.. @Sweeper